# How to create a custom shortcut on Slack?

Tags: slack

I'd like to be able to use a character to stand-in for typing a long URL in Slack.

Instead of

```
https://www.thisiswaytoolongtotypeeachtime.com/ID/123456
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
^123456
```

or an equivalent with a constant prefix and have Slack know to convert my input to the full URL.

My root URL doesn't change, just the item ID.

Does this functionality exist?

Comment: Which version of slack? Desktop or web?

Comment: Desktop version is preferable